# LibGDX Shader inactivates important SpriteBatch methods

Tags: opengl, libgdx, glsl

I'm working on a game and added a shader, which fades everythin into grayscale and then into black. The shader itself works fine, but when I start it some functions of the Spritebatch and the Sprites stop to work. Color-changes are ignored and the Alpha of anything is always 1. These methods are usually responsible for graphical changes which work very good when the default shader is used:

```
sprite.setColor(Color.RED);
sprite.setAlpha((float)lifeTime/100f);
sprite.draw(pBatch);
```

This code colors a pop up red, changes the alpha and then draws it. When the shader is on, it just draws it, like the first two lines wouldn't exist.

Here's the shader's code:

vertex:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

fragment:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

uniform float u_fade;

void main() {
        float gray_fade = u_fade;
        float dark_fade = 1;
        if(u_fade >= 1){
            gray_fade = 1;
            dark_fade = 2-u_fade;
        }

        vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgba;
        float gRed   = color.r - (color.r - (0.299*color.r +  0.587*color.g + 0.114*color.b))* gray_fade;
        float gGreen = color.g - (color.g - (0.299*color.r +  0.587*color.g + 0.114*color.b))* gray_fade;
        float gBlue  = color.b - (color.b - (0.299*color.r +  0.587*color.g + 0.114*color.b))* gray_fade;
        vec3 grayscale = vec3(gRed * dark_fade, gGreen * dark_fade, gBlue * dark_fade);


        gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale, color.a);

}
```

Comment: I take it you didn't write the shader yourself?

Comment: I wrote both with the help of a tutorial and modified the fragment shader a lot to make it fit to my game. The vertex shader is mostly the same

Comment: OK, just curious. It sounds like a slick-looking effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shader is ignoring the vertex color of the sprite.

Put the declaration `varying vec4 v_color;` into your fragment shader and change the last line to:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(grayscale*v_color.rgb, color.a*v_color.a);
```

---

Edit:

It occurred to me that the above would defeat the grayscale setting and would be a pain to deal with if some of the sprites in your scene are colored. So instead, leave that `gl_FragColor` line alone, and move the multiplication up to where you sample the texture color:

```
vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords) * v_color;
```

---

There is also a big inefficiency in your shader, calculating the same dot product three times! Also, I think there are cases where doing your calculation with the whole vector at once may be faster than doing it separately manually.

So I would change those five lines in the middle to:

```
vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
float grayValue = dot(color.rgb, vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.1144));
vec3 grayscale = (color.rgb - (color.rgb - grayValue) * gray_fade) * dark_fade;
```

Regarding the `if` statement in your shader: In general, branching statements have a very significant impact when in a fragment shader and should be avoided. But in this case, the branch is an if statement on a uniform, so I'm not sure if it would have any significant impact, because it will evaluate the same throughout a draw call. Maybe someone else can chime in. If this did cause a big performance issue, you could get around it by replacing `u_fade` with `u_gray_fade` and `u_dark_fade` and moving this calculation out of the shader.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now (almost) fine, but I think I can do the rest on my own :)
And thank you very much for the hint on the performance. I'm quite new to shaders and was happy when I just made these shaders work :D
I'l keep the performance hints in mind when I write my next shaders ;)